# Release borrowing in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying Rust and have some issues with understanding "borrowing".

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 10;
    let mut a = 6;
    let mut y = &mut x;

    *y = 6;
    y = &mut a;

    x = 15;
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

And I've got an error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `x` because it is borrowed
 --> <anon>:9:5
  |
4 |     let mut y = &mut x;
  |                      - borrow of `x` occurs here
...
9 |     x = 15;
  |     ^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `x` occurs here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `x` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> <anon>:10:20
   |
4  |     let mut y = &mut x;
   |                      - mutable borrow occurs here
...
10 |     println!("{}", x);
   |                    ^ immutable borrow occurs here
11 | }
   | - mutable borrow ends here
```

How can I release `x` from "`y`-borrowing"?

Comment: You just need to start [thinking in scopes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/references-and-borrowing.html#thinking-in-scopes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently a limitation of the Rust borrow checker, often referred to as "non lexical lifetimes" (NLL). The problem here is that the when you assign a reference to a variable (`let mut y = &mut x;`) the reference has to be valid for the entire scope of the variable. This means that "x is borrowed" lasts for the entire scope of `y`. So the compiler doesn't care about the line `y = &mut a;`!

You can read a lot more (technical) discussion about this [here at the tracking issue](https://github.com/aturon/rust-roadmap/issues/16).

EDIT: non-lexical lifetimes have landed some time ago, so your code should compile fine now.